# Magento 2 - How to customize email items?

Tags: magento2, orders, email, items, print

If you buy a configurable product, then all options are showing in the invoice for example at `www.example.com/sales/order/print/order_id/14807/`

My team wants me to remove all the configurable options and only show the product name.

[image]

I figured out, that the layout is here:

**vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_print.xml**

this is the template:

**vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml**

it contains this line, which is reponsible for the items being rendered:

```
<?= $block->getItemHtml($item) ?>
```

So I analysed the method in the block

**vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Items\AbstractItems.php**

```
public function getItemHtml(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $item)
{
    $type = $this->_getItemType($item);

    $block = $this->getItemRenderer($type)->setItem($item);
    $this->_prepareItem($block);
    return $block->toHtml();
}
```

but I have no clue how I have to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so closed on finding out the answer on yourself.

If you dig further, you will find the item renderer uses item template `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml`
You can just override this template and remove the option display from line 19-28

Or with a better DI plugin approach, create a **afterGetItemOptions** plugin to `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder` to return an empty array.

If you need to modify other product types too, you need to find out their own renderer class or template

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no clue on how to find that template, I tried to echo it into a logfile, but it showed nothing. I will try and upvote and accept if it works, thx :)

Comment: that is driven by layout xml files, if you do a search for 'sales.email.order.renderers', you will find multiple sales_email_order_renderers.xml files defining the renderer for different product types, you can also create your own renderer. 
There is no renderer for configurable defined, so it uses default renderer

Comment: Nice, now I understand, thank you so much mate!